# Derived typescript class type not accepted as it's own base type

Tags: typescript

I have a bit of code that should work, but I realize now doesn't because the constructor signatures are different for the types.

Example:

```
module test {
    export class A {
        constructor(a: string, b: string) { }

        static doSomething(a: typeof A): number { return 0; }
    }
}

module test {
    export class B extends A {
        constructor() { super("0", "1"); }
    }

    export class C extends B {
        static n = A.doSomething(C);
        x: number;

        constructor(c: C) { super(); }
    }
}
```

'A.doSomething(C)' fails because the constructors are not compatible between the types (because one type value must properly represent the two types in case 'new' is used).  I know the REASON why, but is there no way (other than duck-typing) to specify a specific base type required?  If not, this is a big limitation in my books, and there needs to be a "baseof" besides just "typeof".  If duck-typing is required, then the answer is simply "no". ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I know one way to solve the issue is to put "<any>" before the type, so

```
A.doSomething(<any>C);
```

or

A.doSomething(<A><any>C);

Edit:

The only solution I found was to make the constructor parameters the same for at least the first 2 parameters, which is a compromise that works fine for my situation ...

```
module test {
    export class A {
        constructor(a: string, b: string) { }

        static doSomething(a: typeof A): number { return 0; }
    }
}

module test {
    export class B extends A {
        constructor(a: string, b: string) { super(a, b); }
    }

    export class C extends B {
        static n = A.doSomething(C);
        x: number;

        constructor(a: string, b: string, c?: C) { super(a, b); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the error makes sense.  To qualify as a `typeof A` in your example you must satisfy two conditions:

1. Have a function `doSomething` that takes in a `typeof A` and returns a number
2. Have a 'newable' function that takes in two strings and returns an `A`

`typeof C` just doesn't match that interface on the second point.  The problem isn't expressing what you're trying to do.

What I would do is create an interface that represents the set of features you're requiring the input of `doSomething` to have to get its job done.  It doesn't matter that `typeof A` wasn't explicitly created to implement that interface.  If it matches everything that's asked for, you can pass it in.

Here's your example reworked:

```
// This is the important bit here
interface DoSomethingParam {
    doSomething(a: DoSomethingParam): number;
}

module test {
    export class A {
        constructor(a: string, b: string) { }

        static doSomething(a: DoSomethingParam): number { return 0; }
    }
}

module test {
    export class B extends A {
        constructor() { super("0", "1"); }
    }

    export class C extends B {
        static n = A.doSomething(C);
        x: number;

        constructor(c: C) { super(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good with one method, but is not good if someone is expected to keep an interface in sync with a large class.  The point was to reduce work, not add to it. ;)  Besides, as I stated, using interfaces is like duck-typing, which is what I already mentioned.  Looks like using <any> is the best, and fastest, solution, and can easily be changed to the strong type using "<A><any>" if need be.  The solution I choose was actually to make the constructors accept the first parameter as the same one, and the rest optional for the derived type.

Comment: Just to add, there are also a lot of private variables on my actual class that I need, and interfaces (duck typing) means any object that matches it can be passed in, but it would fail.  The solution needs to lock in with the actual class type, not an interface (in my case anyhow).